# How to get specific value from GeoJSON object

Tags: javascript, json, geojson

I have the below posted array of GeoJSON points. I would like to be able to access the properties of each value in the GeoJSON array separately. For example, for the item of index 3 i would like to get

`"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":6.7368576747845,51.1141914104954]}"`,

I posted my attempts below but it does not work and returns `undefined`.
Please let me know how to access each element of the array separately so that I can get the value of the `coordinates` and `type`.

**Array of GeoJSON points**:

```json
[
    "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73648711211944,51.1144539430392]}",
    "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73628689838002,51.1141803601161]}",
    "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73648765865954,51.1141088970156]}",
    "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.7368576747845,51.1141914104954]}",
    "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73641043458919,51.1141123530415]}",
    "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73655920234526,51.1144536412875]}",
    "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73614395402386,51.1142745754592]}",
    "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73642965248497,51.1141830888474]}",
    "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73641750225145,51.1144305273589]}",
    "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73671503777408,51.1141886499952]}"
]
```

**Code**

```js
console.log("this.centerPointsAsGeoJSONArray[0].coordinates: ",this.centerPointsAsGeoJSONArray[0].type);

console.log("this.centerPointsAsGeoJSONArray[0].coordinates: ",this.centerPointsAsGeoJSONArray[0]['coordinates']);

console.log("this.centerPointsAsGeoJSONArray[0].coordinates: ",this.centerPointsAsGeoJSONArray[0]["coordinates"]);
```

Comment: After loading the data, use `this.centerPointsAsGeoJSONArray = this.centerPointsAsGeoJSONArray.map(JSON.parse);` and after that, you can access the data as you expected. (also please don't tag questions with unrelated tags like angular)

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if your GeoJSON points are an array of strings, rather than an array of objects. I would suggest parsing the string as JSON first, using:
`JSON.parse(this.centerPointsAsGeoJSONArray[0])` to convert to an object, and then accessing the required property.

Edit - Based on @Chris-G comment, using this.centerPointsAsGeoJSONArray.map(JSON.parse) is a more elegant approach, unless the original data format as strings of objects need to be preserved.